# Angularjs consuming WCF REST API expecting a byte stream

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, rest

Short and sweet, my question:

**Is it possible to send a byte array stream to a *REST Web API* in Angularjs?**

I have a simple C# Windows Forms test app, and this works perfectly:

[image: Test WCF Rest Consume app]

WCF REST API that expects a byte stream on HTTP Method *POST*, see below:

[image: REST service help]

So as mentioned typically, I would send a byte[] stream of ID's to the API, and this is an example of  the response:

[image: API Response]

The reason why I used POST in design is that most often we would send through a few thousand ID's, so we don't wan't to be limited by GET.

The idea in C# is to get the response, read the stream, and deserialize it using JavascriptSerializer, whereby it is then binded to a Gridview.

API interface **(IService1.cs)**:

[image: Interface]

I have run through a couple of courses on pluralsight, in particular an excellent series by Scott Allen, and have managed to follow on how to consume the GITHUB API with a GET request, I just can't wrap my head around using a POST, submitting ID or an array of ID's and getting something in return. I know there must be a way, but I am clearly missing something. Or just misunderstanding something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Here is some of the Angular I've tried:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('httpExample', [])
  .controller('FetchController', ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache',
    function($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
      $scope.method = 'POST';
      $scope.url = 'https://api.mydomain.local/Service1.svc/balanceOutstandingMatters/d0d5d606-de9a-4c34-a592-b29681a999d7';
      $scope.paramater = '[{"ID":"G0000013"}]';

      $scope.fetch = function() {
        $scope.code = null;
        $scope.response = null;

        $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url, cache: $templateCache}).
          success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = data;
          }).
          error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;
        });
      };

      $scope.updateModel = function(method, url) {
        $scope.method = method;
        $scope.url = url;
      };
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: Show your work as a text instead of image.

Comment: There really isn't a concept of a byte array or byte stream in javascript. You usually store binary data as a Base64 encoded string, i don't think you would be able to serialise this to a .net `Stream`.

Comment: @SonerGönül, I can place my code above from my Windows forms app, as well as the API, but what I have been able to achieve in Angularjs is unfortunately very little. I have followed an example on Angularjs site and have tried to combine the ideas with some other examples. I however, don't know if the concept is possible, because I haven't spotted many examples of stream byte[] in Angularjs.

Comment: @BenRobinson, I haven't thought of that. A .net stream does not equal a Base64 encoded string though right? So, this would get interpreted differently by my API if I understand correctly?